# basic math computation confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x

writing a basic math program to help me understand python math calculation.

if I write

```
x = 15 + 30 + 45
print(x)
```

I get

```
90
```

if I write

```
x = 90 / 3
print(x)
```

I get

```
30.0
```

but if I write

```
def avg3():
    print("This program will calculate the average of 3 scores")
    scores = eval(input("enter 3 scores: "))
    average = scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2] / 3
    avg = str(average)
    print("The average of the input scores is " + avg + ".")

avg3()
```

and input

```
15, 30, 45
```

what is returned is

```
The average of the input scores is 60.0.
```

of course I'm expecting 30. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses in your average, like this:

```
average = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]) / 3
```

Otherwise, you are just dividing `scores[2]` by `3`.

Comment: ok, now I REALLY feel like an idiot :-). Thanks for clearing out the cobwebs.

Answer (score 3):

actually your code is doing something like this :

```
average = 15+30+(45/3) #that's because / has higher precedence than +
```

so to avoid that use parenthesis:

```
average = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]) / 3
```

BTW don't use `eval()` for this:

```
>>> inp=input("enter 3 scores: ")
enter 3 scores: 1,5,6
>>> scores=list(map(int,inp.split(",")))
>>> scores
[1, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

Division has precedence over addition, so you should use parentheses:

```
average = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]) / 3
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
average = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]) / 3
```

it's called  operator precedence, and in python, `/` is "stronger" than `+`.

come to think about it, you should use

```
average = sum(scores)/len(scores)
```

it's easy to read, short to write, and more general.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing the right calculation according to basic arithmetic precedence, but you need to do this:

```
(scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2] ) / 3
```

...for your answer to be 30.

Comment: People with asthma give higher precedence to multiplication? :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add parentheses around:

```
average = scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]
```

So your code will look like:

```
average = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]) / 3
```

Based on order of operations in Python (or any other programming language), division is done before the indexing operator. So, what you really did in your program was:

```
average = scores[0] + scores[1] + (scores[2] / 3)
```

So, overall your complete program is:

```
def avg3():
print("This program will calculate the average of 3 scores")
scores = eval(input("enter 3 scores: "))
average = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]) / 3
avg = str(average)
print("The average of the input scores is " + avg + ".")
```

This should give you correct result when executed. I hope this answers your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is basic arithmetic: Division before addition. You're actually calculating

```
average = scores[0] + scores[1] + (scores[2] / 3)
```

Instead, you need to use parentheses to override the precedence of operators:

```
average = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]) / 3
```